# Вывести все возможные неповторяющие значения из колонки таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

имеется простая таблица с двумя полями id и color, в колонке 7 разных цветов (Красный Зеленый Синий Желтый Фиолетовый Пурпурный Белый) нужно вывести все возможные уникальные сочетания пар цветов.
например Красный - Зелёный, Красный - Синий, Красный - Жёлтый и так далее.
я сделал такой запрос 
select distinct
    least(color,color) as `значение 1`
  , greatest(color, color) as `значение 2`
from colors
но цвета повторяются.
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно составить запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SELECT t1.color, t2.color FROM tablename t1, tablename t2`. Если надо, добавить `WHERE t1.color != t2.color`.

Comment: и к нему `where t1.id != t2.id`

Comment: @Mike А вдруг в разных копиях таблицы id не совпадают...

Answer (score 0):

Огромная благодарность этому человеку Akina, за помощь,
SELECT t1.color, t2.color FROM colors t1, colors t2 WHERE t1.color != t2.color;